# javascript slice without using built in method

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

What's the logic behind array.slice method? I am trying to implement a function to extract a segment of an array without actually using the slice method.

```
function newSlice(array, begin, end) {

for (let i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
return array[i];
}
```

Comment: The logic is described in e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice. If you've had a problem implementing that, give a [mcve].

Comment: make a new array. start at the start-index, add that element to the new array, add one and check that you're not past the end-index. If you are past the end-index, return the new array, otherwise add one to the index you're currently on and do the process again, until you hit the end-index. If no end-index is provided, assume the end-index is (the length of the array)-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the slice method you are just extracting a 'slice' of the array starting from here (begin) to there (end). To implement the slice function yourself try something like this:

```
function newSlice(array, begin, end) {
  let tempArray =[];

  if(end===undefined || end > array.length)
    end = array.length;

  for (let i = begin; i < end; i++) {
    tempArray.push(array[i]);
  }
  return tempArray;
}

myArray =newSlice([8,3,4,5,4],1,3);
```

Here we get a slice from array [8,3,4,5,4] from index 1 to end at index 3 returning [3,4].

Comment: That's great, thanks! May I ask you what would be the output if no end is given or if the end is actually greater than the array's length?

Comment: No problem! We could modify the function to slice to the end of the array if there is no end given or if the end is greater than the array length with this if statement: ```if(end===undefined || end > array.length) end = array.length;```

Comment: Thanks again! Much appreciated!